# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-settings

Trying to migrate using on django and I have read the documentation and still getting an attribute error which I don't know how to debug

```
_init_.py
   def __getattr__(self, name ,):
           """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
            if (_wrapped := self._wrapped) is empty:
               self._setup(name)
                _wrapped = self._wrapped
            val = getattr(_wrapped, name ,)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the complete error message, with traceback. (And side note: you likely mean `__init__.py`, with two leading and trailing underscores, not one.)